# Just writing a test function and reporting a parameter error

Tags: erlang, aes

This is my code which mainly use `crypto` application:

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0]).

test()->        
    application:start(crypto),
    Type = aes_cbc128,      
    Key = <<"3R9p7eUVAw31ULQG">>,
    IVec = <<0:128>>,
    crypto:block_encrypt(Type, Key, IVec, {<<"M2UsytYCU4FD70y5">>,<<"123456">>}).
```

Comment: I am new guy,help

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two function signatures.  This works for me:

```
test()->        
    application:start(crypto),

    Type = aes_gcm, 
    %Type = aes_cbc128,      
    Key = <<"3R9p7eUVAw31ULQG">>,
    IVec = <<0:128>>,
    crypto:block_encrypt(Type, Key, IVec, {<<"M2UsytYCU4FD70y5">>,<<"123456">>}).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:test().
{<<"5%2âJ*">>,
 <<217,210,215,102,59,40,188,57,156,163,170,158,10,239,
   135,85>>}
```

The [docs](https://erldocs.com/21.0/crypto/crypto.html?i=4&search=crypto:#block_encrypt/4) give this function definition:

```
block_encrypt(Type, Key, Ivec, PlainText)
```

In that function clause, `PlainText` must be the type `iodata()`, and whatever `iodata()` may be, it is *not* a tuple.

If you specify a two element tuple for the 4th argument, then you are matching this function clause:

```
block_encrypt(AeadType, Key, Ivec, {AAD, PlainText})
```

And, in that function clause the type for `AeadType` is `aead_cipher()`, which elsewhere on the page is defined as:

```
aead_cipher() = aes_gcm | chacha20_poly1305
```

In other words, `aes_cbc128` is a "Bad argument" for the variable `AeadType`.

Note that there's no formatting in the section of the docs where the type `aead_cipher()` is defined--all the type definitions run together in what looks like one big type definition, so it's a little difficult to tell what's  going on.  It should look like this:

```
stream_cipher() = rc4 | aes_ctr 

block_cipher() = aes_cbc | aes_cfb8 | aes_cfb128 | aes_ige256 | blowfish_cbc 
     | blowfish_cfb64 | des_cbc | des_cfb | des3_cbc | des3_cfb | des_ede3 | rc2_cbc 

aead_cipher() = aes_gcm | chacha20_poly1305 
stream_key() = aes_key() | rc4_key() 
block_key() = aes_key() | blowfish_key() | des_key()| des3_key() 
aes_key() = iodata()
```

.

Comment: @linanjing, Actually, I just looked at the source code, and the first function clause that your function call matches is: `block_encrypt(Type, Key0, Ivec, Data) -> ...`.  Note that there are no `when` guards, so `Data` will match anything, e.g. a tuple.  The function body then examines Data with a case statement, and the case statement is wrapped in a macro that calls `error(badarg)` if an error occurs.  The source code is too convoluted for me to pinpoint how a tuple causes an error, which then triggers the call to `error(badarg)`.

Comment: I have the version OTP 22, crypto-4.5 and the source code seems clear for me.

Comment: @Pascal,  Great!  Now get back to plagiarizing people's answers.  I'm about to answer another question, so be sure to copy my answer again.

Answer (score -1):

The function crypto:bloc_encrypt/4 accepts several set of parameters:

> block_encrypt(Type, Key, Ivec, PlainText) -> CipherText | Error
>
> block_encrypt(AeadType, Key, Ivec, {AAD, PlainText}) -> {CipherText, CipherTag} | Error
>
> block_encrypt(aes_gcm | aes_ccm, Key, Ivec, {AAD, PlainText, TagLength}) -> {CipherText, CipherTag} | Error

In your code you have selected the second one. In this case, you must use as first parameter a "aead_cypher"

> aead_cipher() = aes_gcm | aes_ccm | chacha20_poly1305

If you want to use the Type parameter, then it is the first set of parameter that must be used with only Plaintext as last parameter instead of {AAD, PlainText}. BTW the Type you selected in your example is not correct, I guess you want aes_128_cbc.

```
1> application:start(crypto). 
ok
2> Type = aes_128_cbc.
aes_128_cbc
3> Key = <<"3R9p7eUVAw31ULQG">>.
<<"3R9p7eUVAw31ULQG">>
4> IVec = <<0:128>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>>
5> Aes = aes_gcm.
aes_gcm
6> crypto:block_encrypt(Type, Key, IVec, <<"1234567890123456789">>).
<<242,220,105,109,252,235,224,216,46,180,149,145,37,129,
  35,194>>
7>  crypto:block_encrypt(Aes, Key, IVec, {<<"M2UsytYCU4FD70y5">>,<<"1234567890123456789">>}).   
{<<53,37,50,226,74,42,229,68,133,9,224,144,125,216,121,49,
   13,225,4>>,
 <<188,96,67,137,208,176,32,237,177,144,147,152,84,130,
   225,98>>}
8>
```

Comment: Blatant plagiarism.

Comment: Well, my dear 7stud, I use to capture some question and write the answer later when I am in the bus going to work, or going back home. So when I post the answer, I do not think to check if there is already an answer. Obviously this question have only one possible answer, so mine is the same as yours. But if your ego is injured, I may consider to remove it. BTW, you didn't notice that the original message is too short to use aes_128_cbc, it is why I used a longer one.

Comment: *So when I post the answer, I do not think to check if there is already an answer.*--Everyone else does.  And, there is a mistake in my answer that you seemed to have made as well...Hmmmm.